# jQuery Animate Won't Work (even samples don't)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to get a simple jQuery animation to work and I can't seem to make it happen. I'm not sure if I'm overlooking a simple syntax issue or something bigger. The samples I've found online don't seem to work either, so I figured I'd try to get a second opinion.

The relevant portions of the head is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

$('.menu_ul li').mouseenter(
function() {
    $('#menuitem1').animate({
        'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to bottom, #1058c4 0%, #1058c4 100%)',
        'color' : '#ffffff'
    },500);
}
);


$('.menu_ul li').mouseleave(
function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'background-image' : 'linear-gradient(to bottom, #A2A2A2 0%, #7D7D7D 100%)',
        'color' : '#343434'
    },500);
}
);

});
</script>
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<ul class="menu_ul" style="display:block;position:absolute">
    <li id="menuitem1"><a href="?content=home">HOME</a></li>
    <li id="menuitem2"><a href="?content=home">PLAYLIST</a></li>
    <li id="menuitem3"><a href="?content=home">COMMUNITY</a></li>
    <li id="menuitem4"><a href="?content=home">ABOUT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS for it as follows:

```
.menu_ul li {   
    padding-top:13px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    color:#343434;
    width:237px;
    height:35px;    
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #A2A2A2 0%, #7D7D7D 100%); 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The jQuery core `.animate()` method doesn't animate colours. You have to include the colour plug in or jQuery UI.

Comment: Ahhh, I see! That worked. How should I go about getting the 'background-image' to work?

Comment: I can't - I figured that out. I'll have to change how exactly I'm doing the colors. Thanks!

Comment: Like @nnnnnn said, you need the [jQuery Color Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to animate colors (font,background,etc). You may need to do some hackery to get the background image/gradient to animate though - maybe change the opacity of a div behind your ul?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to change the background gradient with an opacity change on a secondary element:

HTML

```
<ul class="menu_ul" style="display:block;position:absolute">
    <li id="menuitem1"><a href="?content=home">HOME</a><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li id="menuitem2"><a href="?content=home">PLAYLIST</a><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li id="menuitem3"><a href="?content=home">COMMUNITY</a><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li id="menuitem4"><a href="?content=home">ABOUT US</a><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('.menu_ul a').mouseenter(
    function() {
        $(this).siblings('span').animate({
            'opacity' : 1
        },500);
    }
);


$('.menu_ul a').mouseleave(
    function() {
        $('.menu_ul span').animate({
            'opacity' : 0
        },500);
    }
);
```

CSS

```
.menu_ul li {
    padding:12px 0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    color:#343434;
    width:237px;
    height:35px;
    position:relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #A2A2A2 0%, #7D7D7D 100%); 
}
.menu_ul a,
.menu_ul span{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}
.menu_ul a{
    z-index:1;
    line-height:55px;
    display:block;
}
.menu_ul span{
    opacity:0;
    z-index:0;
    display:block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #A2A2A2 0%, #000000 100%); 
}
```

[jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/6J4n3/)

---

**But let's be real here - CSS3 is better.** (depending on the browser support needed)

HTML

```
<ul class="menu_ul" style="display:block;position:absolute">
    <li id="menuitem1"><a href="?content=home">HOME</a></li>
    <li id="menuitem2"><a href="?content=home">PLAYLIST</a></li>
    <li id="menuitem3"><a href="?content=home">COMMUNITY</a></li>
    <li id="menuitem4"><a href="?content=home">ABOUT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.menu_ul li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:237px;
}
.menu_ul a{
    margin:0;
    padding:12px 0;
    display:block;
    color:#343434;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #A2A2A2 0%, #7D7D7D 100%);
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.menu_ul a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #A2A2A2 0%, #000000 100%); 
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/6J4n3/1/).